# matplotlib hangs on mac osx and graph is not displayed

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I am using Mac Yosemite and Anaconda's distribution for Python 3.4. Whenever I do

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 ...
 plt.semilogy(x, y)
 plt.show()
```

an empty window pops up in a hanged up state.

I saw a similar post: [Matplotlib not showing up in Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=matplotlib%20MAC), which recommended using

```
sudo port install py25-matplotlib +cairo+gtk2
sudo port install py26-matplotlib +cairo+gtk2
```

Since I am using python 3.4, I tried

```
sudo port install py34-matplotlib +cairo+gtk2
```

The installation went fine, but when I tried to `import matplotlib` on the Python console inside PyCharm, I get the following error:

```
Backend GTKCairo is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
Failed to enable GUI event loop integration for 'gtk'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_console_utils.py", line 498, in do_enable_gui
enable_gui(guiname)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/inputhook.py", line 479, in enable_gui
return gui_hook(app)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/inputhook.py", line 227, in enable_gtk
from pydev_ipython.inputhookgtk import create_inputhook_gtk
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/inputhookgtk.py", line 19, in <module>
import gtk, gobject
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named 'gtk'
```

1. What could be the issue?
2. I couldn't locate any `gtk` module within PyCharm, but i found `PyGTK`, `PyGTKCodeBuffer`, `PyGTKImageView`, etc. Is there any website for the `gtk` module?

*** EDIT ***

I solved this problem by adding `Interactive : True` in the `matplotlibrc` file.

Comment: PyGTK is where the Python gtk module comes from. Try installing that one and see if it fixes it.

Comment: you should answer your own question since you found the solution, I nearly missed your edit containing details of what you did

Answer (score 3):

I got it working by following the instructions in [this blog post](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2015/03/26/python-matplotlib-hangs-and-shows-nothing-mac-os-x/).

In a nutshell, replace:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

with the following:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

and a graph window opens (for me it opened in the background hidden behind my IDE so at first I thought nothing had happened)

Answer (score 2):

For those using IPython like me, you can type :

```
%matplotlib auto
```

works on both Linux and MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

You are write in this post:
    ply.show()

The correct form is plt.show(). Is this your error? or you only write wrong on this post

Comment: no, in my code, I used `plt.show()`. It was a typo while writing this question.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using port with anaconda?

From within your conda environment (i.e. after typing from the command line `source activate my_env` where my_env is the name of your environment):

```
condo update conda
conda install matplotlib
conda install pyqt
```