# matplotlib.show() seemingly not doing anything

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to get a simple python program to show a graph. I'm running Python 3.9 on Mac Catalina. My code is:

```
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(1,120,120)
y = (2*10**-5)**2 + ((0.001)/(x))**2

plt.plot(x, y) 
plt.show()
```

I've tried following the instructions laid out in this: [matplotlib hangs on mac osx and graph is not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280595/matplotlib-hangs-on-mac-osx-and-graph-is-not-displayed)

Namely, changing `Interactive: False` to `Interactive: True` in the `matplotlibrc` file, which didn't make any difference, and replacing:

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`
with the following:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

But that hasn't worked either (I checked to see if the graph had gotten lost behind my terminal or anywhere else, and I couldn't find it so I'm assuming it hasn't showed).

In my `matplotlibrc` file, it has `backend: Agg`, but when I type `matplotlib.get_backend()` into my terminal whilst running Python, it returns `"MacOSX"`. Given what it says in the `matplotlibrc`,

```
## ***************************************************************************
## * BACKENDS                                                                *
## ***************************************************************************
## The default backend.  If you omit this parameter, the first working
## backend from the following list is used:
##     MacOSX Qt5Agg Gtk3Agg TkAgg WxAgg Agg
## Other choices include:
##     Qt5Cairo GTK3Cairo TkCairo WxCairo Cairo
##     Qt4Agg Qt4Cairo Wx  # deprecated.
##     PS PDF SVG Template
## You can also deploy your own backend outside of matplotlib by referring to
## the module name (which must be in the PYTHONPATH) as 'module://my_backend'.
#backend: Agg
```

should this not be returning `"Agg"`?

I downloaded both numpy and matplotlib using pip3, and I'd prefer not to use Anaconda if possible, as I seem to have messed up my Windows machine installing and uninstalling there, but that is part of a different question.

When I copy and paste my code directly into the terminal running Python, my graph shows, which I suppose solves the problem of my graph not showing, but then I still have the problem if I want to run longer pieces of code, which would be my next step, as I eventually want to import a graph from matlab and compare it to this plot.

If I change my code to include the solution from the link above, so that my code reads:

```
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
print(matplotlib.get_backend())
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(1,120,120)
y = (2*10**-5)**2 + ((0.001)/(x))**2

plt.plot(x, y) 
plt.show()
```

It outputs TkAgg, but then still doesn't show my graph. Why is this happening, and what can I do to fix it so that I can make graphs without copying and pasting into the terminal?

Comment: Thanks! As an aside though, my code, when put into the terminal, still made the graph fine with show instead of show(). Does python automatically fix things like this?

Comment: This anaconda installation was done on my windows machine, which I think I might end up having to permanently reset (hence why I'd prefer to avoid it), whereas this code is running solely on the Mac.

Comment: Just to mention the reason the `Agg` from the matplotlibrc file is being ignored is because that line is commented out: it begins with a `#` symbol. Remove that and matplotlib will use that line to decide on the backend.

Comment: @tmdavison, Every single line in that file starts with at least one # symbol, does that mean that nothing in the file is being used? Why would it be like that?

Comment: Yes that's right. It means that the defaults are being used for all values. So, if there's anything you want to customise, you need to uncomment the relevant line before it will have any effect. You can read more about the matplotlibrc file [here](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html): Specifically, note the comment in the header: `Blank lines, or lines starting with a comment symbol, are ignored, as are trailing comments.`

Comment: Ah, I see! Unfortunately uncommenting that line still doesn't fix my problem, but thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after faffing around with various dependencies, installing brew, installing various packages and uninstalling various packages, **uninstalling matplotlib and reinstalling matplotlib seems to have solved the problem**, and graphs now output when a .py program is ran in the terminal (e.g. python3 program.py in the terminal). I'm not sure whether any of the packages I installed made it work, or whether it was simply the act of uninstalling and reinstalling, but at least now it works. I'm happy to put my terminal history down at some point if anyone is curious or comes across the same issue.